# WPA3 Personal auth_alg value in journal

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wpa3

my question is about WPA3 on 20.04 and the corresponding journal output
for the NetworkManager.

When I connect to a WPA3 Personal network, I see the following lines:

```
key_mgmt sae ft-sae (which is ok)
auth_alg open
```

The part open confuses me, since the info I can find describes open only with the old WEP
Nevertheless the wpa_supplicant.conf states that if auth_alg is not set, the default is OPEN with LEAP enabled if set.

```
# auth_alg: list of allowed IEEE 802.11 authentication algorithms
# OPEN = Open System authentication (required for WPA/WPA2)
# SHARED = Shared Key authentication (requires static WEP keys)
# LEAP = LEAP/Network EAP (only used with LEAP)
# If not set, automatic selection is used (Open System with LEAP enabled if
# LEAP is allowed as one of the EAP methods).
```

When I check the wpa_cli output for the corresponding device with

```
wpa_cli -i DEV status
```

I see the following output:

```
key_mgmt=SAE
pmf=1
mgmt_group_cipher=BIP
sae_group=19
wpa_state=complete
ieee80211ac=1
```

Which leads me to the conclusion that the WPA3 connection was correctly established, also the AP shows the device as WPA3 connected device.

The point I don't get and what concerns me is, why auth_alg open appears in NetworkManager for WPA3, which is in fact not present with WPA2.

Side info:

- Connection was purely setup with GUI, no modification on .confs
- Behaviour can be seen on mulitple connections with WPA3 APs
- Used Kernel 5.13

Any suggestions or experiences from your side?
Same behaviour?

Thank you for any help or experience from your side!

Answer (score 0):

See the page and search for word "open" here:  https://www.netspotapp.com/blog/wifi-security/what-is-wpa3.html

I think you can be calm concerning OPEN algorithm. It is OK.